# Determine which of the following is an information set of the dual code of the binary Hamming code of length 7.

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

Determine which of the following is an information set of the dual code of the binary Hamming code of length 7.

- {1,2,3}
- {1,2,4}
- {3,5,6}

I dont understand how to proceed with this problem.

This is a Homework problem

I dont need the answer but I want to know how to work it out.

Can someone please help where to find information about this problem or how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check your lecture notes for the definitions of the terms "information set", "dual code" and "binary Hamming code".

The next step will be to check whether those sets are information sets of the dual code of the binary Hamming code. The most simple way would be to write down the entire Hamming code of length 7, then check for each of your sets whether the code word corresponding to this set satisfies the property of being in the dual code of the Hamming code of length 7.

Comment: How to check ? I dont have the Hamming code of length 7

Comment: The definition of the Hamming code should be in your notes somewhere. Use the definition to generate the code.

Comment: Its wriiten that parity bits occupy $2^m$ positions and other are messages

Comment: So for all possible combinations of 4 message bits, you need to write down the string of 7 bits containing those 4 message bits and the appropriate parity bits as per the definition of the Hamming code.

Comment: I seriously dont get your point

Comment: Do you mind explaining

Comment: Let's consider the 4-bit message 0110. We want to put it into a Hamming code. The 7-bit Hamming code for this message must look like 011X0XX, where the Xs are parity bits in positions 4, 2, 1.

Comment: From the definition of Hamming code parity, the parity bits are uniquely determined by the message bits, and the final hamming code is 0110011.

Comment: So then how to find the dual code?

Comment: A bitstring is a dual word if shares an even number of 1s with every codeword. Example: the dual code of the code {0000000,1100000} is the set of all bitstrings where the first and second bits are equal.